# Preventing user from entering zero but allowing other numbers that contain zero

Tags: c#, events, keypress

I have a TextBox control. I have set my `KeyPress` event of the TextBox so that the user is only allowed to enter digits:

```
private void txtbxRecurEveryXWeeks_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
   {
       e.Handled = true;
   }
}
```

But in addition to that I do not want the user to set the value of the TexBot to zero "0". But they still should be allowed to enter "10" or "3400" as the value. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably best to ignore the keypress event and handle the lost focus event and check and ensure the value isn't `0` when the user is done typing.

EDIT: It was pointed out that the user could type "000" and lose focus which would cause this to fail. You can check and confirm the textbox has a value and parse it as an `int` to confirm it isn't 0.

```
private void txtbxRecurEveryXWeeks_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int value;
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtbxRecurEveryXWeeks.Text) 
        && int.TryParse(txtbxRecurEveryXWeeks.Text, out value) 
        && value > 0)
    {
        //Do something like clear the textbox value
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree with last point. I would do a lost focus, or complain on submit

Comment: Yes I have added it on submit too but before that I should also prevent entering zero because then I have another label on the form that is going to say "Every 0 weeks" which does not make sense. I'm goona try your solution and if it worked, you will have the right answer.

Comment: @GrantWinney definitely agree. Updated to use `int.TryParse`.

Answer (score 0):

In the assumption that you use [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms), consider using the [`NumericUpDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx) control to enter numbers. It has the `Minimum` property, which you could set to `1` to avoid zero input.

Answer (score 0):

Use NumericUpDown with minimum value = 1 and hidden up and down buttons.

```
    numericUpDown1.Minimum = 1;
    numericUpDown1.Controls[0].Hide();
```